# Execute SQL on AWS EMR Spark cluster via thrift server JDBC from python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, jdbc, amazon-emr

I have a AWS EMR Spark cluster (version emr-5.25.0)

I need to implement a way to issue spark SQL queries to spark via an external python client.

Assuming the EMR master node has a reachable host name, and the thrift server is running, **how can I setup a JDBC connection from python and issue a SQL query to spark and get the results back?**

How would I handle long running jobs?

I know that it is possible to establish JDBC connection using `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` class. I guess I could try to create a python wrapper over this JAR ... but ideally I would prefer to handle the connection in python if possible. Since JDBC is generic, I would assume there exists some generic python JDBC library that I could use to connect to spark thrift server?

Comment: This post makes me fear for the future. I'm envisioning a Rube Goldberg machine of coding libraries.

Comment: @JacobH I chuckled to myself at how many buzz words I used in the question title

Comment: Is [This](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/jdbc-connection-emr/) related to your question?

Comment: @Lamanus precisely. that article discusses how to establish JDBC connection (java) to query EMR/spark. The question is what is a good way to do this from python.